# I need to transpose data and reorder - Data changes every month but Column names remain static

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Original File Example:

[image]

Requesting help to Convert to this (this needs to run monthly and update)

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You need to provide some actual details in your question so we can help. Vague screenshots of data with no explanation is not going to work. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: This makes almost no sense.  I would ask someone why in the world they would want three pivot sequences of two followed up by two arbitrary pivots.  I would get the source data making the first sheet and just make it like the second but why in the world would anyone want to combine two seperate columns into a shared column without a designation of what was what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like this with UNION:

```
-- Example table
WITH T (A,B,C,D,E,F,[Jan-OCV],[Feb-OCV],[Mar-OCV],[OWNER],[Jan-ACT],[Feb-ACT],[Mar-ACT])AS
(SELECT 'AA11','A1',777,'XYZ',222,'aasd',123,231,199,'ZZZZ',123,456,789
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'BB22','A2',8777,'XYZZZZ',3333,'bbbbbb',223,433,231,'YYYYY',225,437,231
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'CC12','A3',9777,'ZZZ',567,'asdfasfdaasd',788,785,789,'TTTTT',599,759,795
)
-- Query 

SELECT A,B,D,C_E,[OWNER],[Month],OCV, ACT, F 
FROM 
(
SELECT A,B,D,NULL as C_E, [OWNER],'Jan' as [Month],[Jan-OCV] as OCV, [Jan-ACT] as ACT, F, 1 as [Order]
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B,D,NULL as C_E, [OWNER],'Feb' as [Month],[Feb-OCV] as OCV, [Feb-ACT] as ACT, F, 2 as [Order]
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B,D,NULL as C_E, [OWNER],'Mar' as [Month],[Mar-OCV] as OCV, [Mar-ACT] as ACT, F, 3 as [Order]
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B,D, C as [C_E], [OWNER],NULL as [Month],C as OCV, NULL as ACT, F, 4 as [Order]
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B,D, E as [C_E], [OWNER],NULL as [Month],E as OCV, NULL as ACT, F, 5 as [Order]
FROM T
) as T1 ORDER BY A,B,D,[Order]
```

Comment: Thank you - this helped. regards

Comment: @ANASI-Newbie Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer worked for you, please [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)